# Asp.Net.Core Webapi application with sqlite cannot get or post data while deploy it to docker

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker, sqlite

I have .NET webapi application with sqlite as database run on locally, I try to deploy it to docker container using docker build, and everything was fine with docker

but when I try hit the API to get and insert data but I got server error 500;

with exection :

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
  Connection id "0HM9T6FK8IAR1", Request id "0HM9T6FK8IAR1:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
   ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Articles'.
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Article.Api.Controller.ArticlesController.CreateArticle(CreateArticleDto articleDto)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

here my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-alpine AS publish
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Article.Api.csproj", "./"]


RUN dotnet restore "Article.Api.csproj" --runtime alpine-x64

COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish "Article.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish \
    --no-restore \
    --runtime alpine-x64 \
    --self-contained true \
    /p:PublishTrimmed=true \
    /p:PublishSingleFile=true

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:5.0-alpine AS final

RUN adduser --disabled-password \
    --home /app \
    --gecos '' dotnetuser && chown -R dotnetuser /app

RUN apk upgrade musl

USER dotnetuser
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["./Article.Api", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

I have try to enter the container with container and see the db is there :

```
❯ docker exec -it 21478b99490e sh
~ $ ls
Article.Api                   appsettings.Development.json  article.db
Article.Api.pdb               appsettings.json              libe_sqlite3.so

~ $ cat  appsettings.
cat: can't open 'appsettings.': No such file or directory
~ $ cat  appsettings.json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "DataSource=article.db; Cache=Shared"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the provided stack trace the problem is here:
`---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Articles'.`

The database doesn't contain **Articles** table.